# If $A^k$ is diagonalizable, prove that $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Suppose that $A \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{C})$ and $A$ is invertible. If $A^k$ is diagonalizable for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

I have tried using the fact that the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is dividable by its minimal polynomial and if a matrix is diagonalizable, its minimal polynomial have only simple roots(roots with no repetition). But I can't figure out how to construct minimal/characteristic polynomial of $A^k$ using A or vice-versa.

Comment: That's false. Look at $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo you are right. I have to edit the question. A is invertible

Comment: Do you know the Jordan Form Theorem?

Comment: Outline: Let $\mu(t)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A^k$. Then, $f(t)=\mu(t^k)$ is a polynomial such that $f(A)=\mu(A^k)=0$. Use the fact that $A^k$ is diagonalizable, and hence $\mu(t)$ splits with simple roots, to show that $f(t)$ also splits with simple  roots. Since the minimal polynomial divides $f(t)$ ___ (fill in the blanks). Think about which step uses invertibility. Alternatively, you can look at the Jordan canonical form of $A$, and analyze its $k^{th}$ power to deduce the original matrix has $1\times 1$ Jordan blocks.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes just learned it but don't want to use it if possible

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks! I think i got it.